# Called function should be payable => when trying to set some random value in array inside constructor

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, solidity-0.8.x

A basic smart contract with 2 arrays

```
// This works
uint[5] public mfb;
uint[5] public mfa;


// And this doesn't
uint[] public mfb;
uint[5] public mfa;
```

I'm trying to set value at index 0 inside constructor, for the arrays, but when I try to do so, contract is not deployed. I get this error :

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: Please, include the code as text and not as an image. That makes it much easier to test and suggest changes.

Comment: Yes I have update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error saying "the constructor isn't payable" is a generic error message. Usually it is caused by something breaking inside the constructor.

If the constructor is the commented out code then the cause is that you are using `mfb` array before adding elements. It is initially empty, so `mfb[0]` causes an access out of bounds and the execution reverts.

```
constructor() {
    mfb.push(1000); // Add an element
    mfb[0] = 25;    // now position = 0 is valid, and can be modified
}
```

Comment: Yes that works, Thanks
so basically, for dynamic array we need to use push first, then only we can perform operation using index. Right?

Comment: @BharatSingh You can only access a valid index. An empty array doesn't have valid indices. To grow a dynamic array you have to push elements into it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you send ether while you deploy the contract, you can't send ether when calling a function which is not marked as `payable`, in other words, you can send ether only if the function is marked as `payable`.

> constructor() payable { }